# Double precision not working correctly in mysql when using double type

Tags: mysql, sql, database, t-sql

I have double field in a table. When I deduct a fractional part from double parameter it is giving weird problem.

My amount in table is 0.068

when I deduct 0.06 it becomes

0.0080000000000001

my simple query for update is

```
UPDATE 
     subscriber 
SET 
     balance = balance - _amount
```

where _amount is a Double  paramter

As it is a sort of legacy implementation i can't change the column type at the moment. so needed some workaround inside the query

Comment: Double precision is approximate numeric, i.e. things like this can happen.

Comment: At the moment i can't change the type otherwise i could go for float/decimal. Any thing i can do in above query as a workaround

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: user20160 i have used double in sql server and didn't remember this problem. I have asked for any mysql workaround without changing types

Comment: All dbms products I know, incl SQL Server, have this behavior.

Comment: ok jarlh. I have a practice of always using decimal type in sql server. Might be in the places i have used double type i haven't see the behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change the type you can try something like:

```
UPDATE 
     subscriber 
SET 
     balance = ((balance * 10000) - (_amount * 10000)) / 10000
```

so subtraction doesn't use decimals.

Comment: One problem i have 1 as amount. when i subtracted 0.001234 it becomes 0.9987659999999999 instead of 0.998766

Comment: @KamranShahid Yeah the workaround has limitations but if you use `* 1000000` and `/ 1000000` it might work for those numbers you gave. But if you have more than 10-15 etc decimal places than the workaround will probably not work. Other option is to cast the value to decimal(10, 5) before the subtraction.

Comment: Ok let me try Casting

Comment: i have used UPDATE subscriber SET balance=  CAST( balance AS DECIMAL(20,3)) -  CAST( _amount AS DECIMAL(20,3)) .......... Thanks artm

Answer (score 3):

What is the problem?  `double precision` is a floating point number that uses a binary representation to approximate decimal values.

If you want a precise number, then use a fixed point representation.  Such a column would be declared `decimal`.  You can change this use `alter table`:

```
alter table change column balance decimal(10, 4);  -- or whatever is appropriate
```

In particular, storing monetary values using floating point numbers is not recommended.